# Create Posts from API response without duplicates

Tags: posts, wp-api

I am hoping someone can help with this. I am getting content via an API call to a third party vendor that supplies articles. I need to then add these articles as posts and also make sure I don't duplicate. My API response is json_decoded.

here is my code so far:

```
function call_api($url, $data) {

    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method){
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                              
        break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    // OPTIONS:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

    // EXECUTE:
    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    if(!$result) {
        die("Connection Failure");
    }

    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;

}

$result = call_api('XXXXXX', array("by_community" => "XXXX", 'status' => 'published'));

$response = json_decode($result, true);
```

Comment: Is this the code you are using to get the articles from a third party vendor? Then it is not really relevant to your question. Please show us the code you are using to insert new posts into the WP.

Comment: I do not have the code to insert the posts yet. That is what I am asking for help on :)

Comment: I think you would get better help if you first read some basic [WP Rest API Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/), and maybe some other [tutorials](https://www.google.rs/search?q=insert+post+with+wp+rest+api&rlz=1C1CHBF_enRS810RS810&oq=insert+post+with+wp+rest+api&aqs=chrome..69i57.3847j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and then try to do it yourself, and ask a question with concrete problem you faced.